# Angular template inside reactive form

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

In our application I noticed lots of duplicate code in the HTML of our forms, most input elements have the same structure so I want to create a generic input component that we can use instead to keep the files clean.

The problem I currently have is that there is 1 form that has 2 nested formGroups inside, example:

```
this.addressForm = this.fb.group({

  postalAddress: this.fb.group({
    street: ["", [Validators.required]],
  }),

  visitorAddress: this.fb.group({
    street: [""],
  })
});
```

This leads to my new component's HTML to also have duplicate code due to some forms requiring a formGroupName.

```
<div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form && controlPath && controlName">
<div *ngIf="groupName" [formGroupName]="groupName">
    <mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
        <input type="number" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'number'">
        <mat-error *ngFor="let message of form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['messages']">{{ message | i18n }}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!groupName">
    <mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
        <input type="number" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'number'">
        <mat-error *ngFor="let message of form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['messages']">{{ message | i18n }}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

The code above works fine but as mentioned, I would like to get rid of the duplicate code. I figured this would be a good case for a ng-template but it appears when using a template the nested controls can no longer find the surrounding FormGroup.

Example

```
<div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form && controlPath && controlName">
<div *ngIf="groupName" [formGroupName]="groupName">
    <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-content>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!groupName">
    <ng-content *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-content>
</div>

<ng-template #content>
    <mat-form-field class="w-full">
        <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
        <input type="number" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'number'">
        <mat-error *ngFor="let message of form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['messages']">{{ message | i18n }}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</ng-template>
```

Error:
[image]

Has anyone encountered such a situation and if so, what would be a good way to go about this?

**UPDATE**

After Garbage Collectors answer I refactored my code to the following:

```
<div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form && controlPath && controlName">
<div *ngIf="groupName" [formGroupName]="groupName">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ templateForm: form, templateFormGroup: groupName, templateControlName: controlName }"></ng-container>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!groupName">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="inputTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ templateForm: form, templateControlName: controlName }"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #inputTemplate let-form="templateForm" let-groupName="templateFormGroup" let-controlName="templateControlName">
    <div [formGroup]="form" [formGroupName]="groupName">
        <mat-form-field class="w-full">
            <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'text'">
            <input type="number" matInput [formControlName]="controlName" *ngIf="type === 'number'">
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['required']">{{ 'error.required' | i18n }}</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['email']">{{ 'error.email' | i18n }}</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['invalid']">{{ 'error.form.invalid' | i18n }}</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['minlength']">{{ minLengthError }}</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['pattern']">{{ patternError }}</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngFor="let message of form.get(controlPath)?.errors?.['messages']">{{ message | i18n }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Though the template now has all variables correctly, it cannot find the control path for non-nested forms. I outputted controlName in the template as a test and it is correct. I expect the error occurring due to the formGroupName being null for non-nested forms.
Error:
[image]

Comment: This condition inside the input field looks weird `*ngIf="type === 'text'"` and it can possibly prevent control from rendering, hence you get the error that control doesn't exist. If you want control to be always available, but invisible, I'd rather use styles, e.g. `style="display: none"`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, every isolated piece of code displaying form controls should have a reference to the form where those controls were defined.

**Actions**

- Use `ng-container` instead of `ng-content` to include your templates
- Pass `form` as a parameter to your template
- Assign `form` parameter to `[formGroup]` attribute inside your template

**Template**

```
<ng-template #demoTemplate let-form="demoForm">
  <div [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- Insert the rest of your template here -->
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

**Main component using template**

```
<div [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container 
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="demoTemplate" 
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ demoForm: form }">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Notice that attribute `formGroup` is added in both places, in the template and in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [formControl] instead of formControlName
You can pick nested variables via the get command, for instance `form.get('Address.Street')`

More explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668699/6019056

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).