# formGroupName cannot be set to null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a dynamic angular form with RxFormBuilder (Angular 13.x). I would like to set the `formGroupName` to null if my input doesn't belong to a nested field, otherwise set it.

I expected this attributes to be removed if set to `null`, but I ended up getting the error below:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')
```

Here is a simple example to illustrate:

**Component**

```js
class A {
  @prop()
  id!: number;
}

@Component({ ... })
  model: A;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
  ) {
    this.model = new A();
    this.form = this._formBuilder.formGroup(A, this.model);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="null"> <-- here
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput name="id" formControlName="id" type="text" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

For me, this `<ng-container [formGroupName]="null">` should become `<ng-container>` and not raising this error because it hasn't been set.

Is there something I'm missing, or it's a default behavior ?

Comment: try this: `[formGroupName]="'null'"` but actually, will be great to avoid of using the `null` as a FormGroup name

Comment: I already tested it, even if I guess it works as `formGroupName="null"`. Which is : looking for a sub key named `null`.

Comment: Why you expect that setting directives input variable to null will remove the directive? Generally speaking `null` is absolutely legal as `@Input()` value. In your case, by adding directive `formGroupName` you created FormGroupName class instance that expects variable `formGroupName` to be set to something meaningful, not `null`. Use *ngIf="boolean; else otherTemplate" if you want different appearance depending the form model.

Comment: I thought it could behave like attribute and then not be set if pass to null. That's dumb of me, and you're right about it. But, since we can pass a null value (see FormGroupName) I would expect it to work like this. Thanks for your clarity!

Answer (score 2):

For all the folks who encountered the same problem - just use [formControl] instead of formControlName. Here's code example

TS:

```
getFormControl(fieldName: string, nestedObjectName: string) {
  const name = (nestedObjectName ? `${nestedObjectName}.` : '') + fieldName;
  return this.form.get(name);
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    name="id"
    [formControl]="getFormControl('fieldName', 'parentName')"
    type="text"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

Newer versions of angular allows you to pick nested variables by get operator. For instance you have formGroup with values like this:

```
{
 Client: 'John Smith',
 Address: {
   Street: 'Whatever 5'
 }
}
```

You can pick the `Client` variable via comment `form.get('Client')`,
and `Street` via `form.get('Address.Street')`

Answer (score 0):

If Ashot's comment didn't help, consider using `*ngIf` like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!belongsToNestedField">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput name="id" formControlName="id" type="text" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>

<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container *ngIf="belongsToNestedField" [formGroupName]="whatever">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput name="id" formControlName="id" type="text" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Something else you could try, although I'm not sure if it would work, is setting the formGroupName to an empty string conditionally with a ternary operator:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="belongsToNestedField ? 'whatever' : ''">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput name="id" formControlName="id" type="text" />
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

You could also look at conditional validation in the component instead: [link to docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators#conditional-validation)

Comment: Yes, your first solution works, that's how I implemented it before coming to ask for help. I was hoping to find a solution to avoid duplicating the code of the input fields. I also tried passing an empty string, that doesn't work either. Thanks for your time!